# Having issues reading json to string

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Have tried several methods described but not winning.  Here is the value ofthe var valuesEntity (this is from Luis integration into bot framework). 
I have not found a way to interrogate this var so that I get a variable with the value of Venue - in this case Bakery.

```
{{
  "$instance": {
    "Venue": [
      {
        "startIndex": 13,
        "endIndex": 19,
        "text": "bakery",
        "type": "Venue"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Venue": [
    [
      "BAKERY"
    ]
  ]
}}
```

Comment: You should share your code so we can help you figure out why it's not working.

Comment: I'm just guessing now.  I tried the answer below but it needs context.  Here is the code .   This is in the BasicBot.cs file as part of the bot framework C# sample.

                        var valuesEntity = luisResults.Entities;  
                     //   var s = valuesEntitiy.Venue[0][0];
                           await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("great");
                    break;
                }

Answer (score 1):

"Venue" is an string[][], Venue[0][0], should return "BAKERY".

This would be a valid json:

```
{
    "$instance": {
        "Venue": [{
            "startIndex": 13,
            "endIndex": 19,
            "text": "bakery",
            "type": "Venue"
        }]
    },
    "Venue": [
        [
            "BAKERY"
        ]
    ]
}
```

You can check for valid json on https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: This needs context, please.  answer = Venue[0][0] doesn't work.

Comment: What does Venue[0][0] return?

Comment: Might be better to ask this way and perhaps MSFT will respond.  I'm using Tutorial: LUIS bot in C# with the Bot Framework 4.x and the sample reads for Intent to switch based on intent.  However, there is no documentation on how to read the top intent for the content in the json object.  Yes, everyone's json object will look different, but if they would simply offer an example of how to read the object based on the sample, that would be awesome.  Or if someone wants to offer a solution, that would be awesome as well!

Comment: Thanks. Enrique.  Venue[0][0] returns "The name 'Venue' does not exist in teh current context"

Comment: I've tried about a dozen checked off answers, but I always get "cannot convert JsonObject to string".  Isn't that what deserialization is all about?

Comment: You have other issue, your string it's not a valid json you have an  extra {} on your string.

Answer (score 0):

The key was to deserialize the Jason object to a Jason string.